# C# increment decrement List values

Tags: c#, list

So sorry for this vague question... its doing my head in...

Basically just a test project, use the [+] key to add a bunch of values into the List.... The arrow keys need to go up and down the List values...

When a new value is added to the list the "historySelected" is reset, so that the 'Up Arrow'.. always selects the last item added in the List first, and then if you keep pressing it, it goes back through the List values.  At anytime if the 'Down Arrow' key is pressed it needs to go back to the previous value in the List of values. At no point should a Up Arrow key followed by a Down Arrow key show the same List value, and vice versa..

The behavior I'm looking for is much like a developer console with a command history, where Up arrow goes further back in history, and Down arrow the opposite.

Again apologies for the code, its been through so many test changes, currently this works going Up arrow to the start of the List value, and then using the Down arrow to go all the back to the highest List index... but the problem is if you go half way through the List (or inbetween anyway), and switch from Up arrow.. to Down arrow.. the values increment/decrement don't act accordingly... I can't seem to get the right codelogic for it.

Any help or suggestions thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ArrowKeys {
    class Program {

        //public static List<string> cmdHistory = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
        public static List<string> cmdHistory = new List<string>();
        public static int cmdHistoryCount = 0;
        public static int historySelected = 0;
        public static int num = 0;
        public static string current = "";

        public enum UpDown {
            reset,
            up,
            down
        };

        public static UpDown LastUpDown;

       static void Main(string[] args) {
            bool running = true;
            while (running) {
                ConsoleKeyInfo kb = Console.ReadKey();
                switch (kb.Key) {
                    case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                        Console.WriteLine("Exit");
                        running = false;
                        return;
                    case ConsoleKey.Add:
                        cmdHistory.Add(num.ToString());
                        cmdHistoryCount++;
                        historySelected= cmdHistoryCount;
                        LastUpDown = UpDown.reset;
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", cmdHistory.Cast<string>().ToArray()));
                        num++;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        UpArrow();
                        LastUpDown = UpDown.up;
                        Console.WriteLine("UpArrow pressed");
                        Console.WriteLine(current);
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        DownArrow();
                        LastUpDown = UpDown.down;
                        Console.WriteLine("DownArrow pressed");
                        Console.WriteLine(current);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public static int Clamp(int value, int min, int max) {
            return (value < min) ? min : (value > max) ? max : value;
        }

        public static void UpArrow() {
            if (cmdHistoryCount != 0) {
                if (LastUpDown == UpDown.down) {
                    if (historySelected - 1 == 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                current = cmdHistory[historySelected - 1];
                    if (historySelected - 1 == 0) {
                    return;
                    }
                    historySelected--;
            }
        }

        public static void DownArrow() {
            if (cmdHistoryCount != 0) {
                if (LastUpDown == UpDown.up) {
                    if (historySelected + 1 > cmdHistoryCount) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                    current = cmdHistory[historySelected - 1];
                    if (historySelected + 1 > cmdHistoryCount) {
                        return;
                    }
                    historySelected++;

            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `At no point should a Up Arrow key followed by a Down Arrow key show the same List value, and vice versa..` I don't understand your cycling behavior... If up goes back in the history and down goes forward (like a console), then if I press up then down I necessarily go back to the same value... What's the twist?

Comment: These two statements seem entirely contradictory: *"At anytime if the 'Down Arrow' key is pressed it needs to go back to the previous value in the List of values" "At no point should a Up Arrow key followed by a Down Arrow key show the same List value"*

Comment: 0,1,2,3,4,5

If the last value shown was 2.. then UpArrow should goto 1 next, if instead you pressed DownArrow, then it should goto 3.

If you kept pressing UpArrow to the startwhere it keeps repeating 0, and the press DownArrow it should goto 1.

And if you kept pressing DownArrow to the end 5, and then pressed UpArrow it should goto 4.

The stuff I've tried just wasn't getting all of it right. 

Sorry for the confussion, the code I posted was somewhat broken..

Comment: The enum last key arrow value used and clamp code was left in from another attempt at trying to get it working right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you simply need to stop your index going out of range.  It's not clear what the existing code was intended to do, but your clarification seems to imply it's not necessary.  Try this:

```
public static void UpArrow()
{
    historySelected = Math.Max(0, historySelected - 1);
    current = cmdHistory[historySelected];
}

public static void DownArrow()
{
    var maxIndex = cmdHistory.Count - 1;
    historySelected = Math.Min(maxIndex, historySelected + 1);
    current = cmdHistory[historySelected];
}
```

Comment: This works! :D (well I added the if (cmdHistory.Count != 0) {} around it to prevent index out of range if the count was 0)..but damn did I complicate it... looking back I think I did get close to this, for UpArrow I was incrementing the historySelected++; then using Clamp, and finally displaying the value for UpArrow, and doing the opposite with Down.. but something was off in how I was doing it. I think I just hate dealing with Lengths and Counts when you always have to subtract 1 to use them for indexes, it seems to throw me off completely when using them.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're looking for correctly, a pair of dueling stacks might work for your case. They're going to give you the FILO/LIFO style item access you're looking for. Drop the List and do something like:

```
var UpStack = new Stack<string>();
var DownStack = new Stack<string>();
```

On "new item"

```
UpStack.Push(newItem);
```

On "Up"

```
DownStack.Push(UpStack.Pop());
```

On "Down"

```
UpStack.Push(DownStack.Pop());
```

If you wanted a "buffer" item that isn't in either of the stacks, that's easy enough to do by just Popping into the buffer item. It's a little more management, because you'd have to push it onto one stack, then pop the other each time, but it's whatever. There's also the Peek() method, which gets the item on top of a Stack without Popping it, so you use that for your display item, as well.